Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid in datagridview with VB.NET
I'm Trying to use event CellEndEdit in datagridview but there is an error
I want when the user makes the DatagridView column empty then a MessageBox appears when the value becomes previous
If I remove the value in the price column the first time then there is no error and then the second time I do the same then an error appears.
For more details I attach a gif file
Is there something wrong with my code ?
Please Guide Me.
Thanks
Public Class Form2
    Public _myTable As New DataTable()
    Public _dr As DataRow
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        _myTable.Columns.AddRange({
                New DataColumn("Code", GetType(String)),
                New DataColumn("Quantity", GetType(Integer)),
                New DataColumn("Price", GetType(Integer)),
                New DataColumn("Discount", GetType(Integer)),
                New DataColumn("Total", GetType(Integer))})
        Me.CenterToScreen()
    End Sub
    Private Sub CalculateTotalqty()
        Dim tot As Double = 0
        For Each item As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim quantity As Double
            If Not IsDBNull(item.Cells("Quantity").Value) Then
                Integer.TryParse(CType(item.Cells("Quantity").Value, String), CInt(quantity))
            End If
            tot += quantity
        Next item
        lblQty.Text = tot.ToString("N2")
    End Sub
    Private Sub CalculateTotalValue()
        Dim tot As Double = 0
        For Each item As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim quantity As Double = 0
            Dim price As Double = 0
            Dim discount As Double = 0
            If Not IsDBNull(item.Cells("Quantity").Value) Then
                Integer.TryParse(CType(item.Cells("Quantity").Value, String), CInt(quantity))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(item.Cells("Price").Value) Then
                Integer.TryParse(CType(item.Cells("Price").Value, String), CInt(price))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(item.Cells("Discount").Value) Then
                Integer.TryParse(CType(item.Cells("Discount").Value, String), CInt(discount))
            End If
            tot += (quantity * price) - (discount)
        Next item
        lblValue.Text = tot.ToString("N")
    End Sub
    Private Sub BtnAddproduct_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAddproduct.Click
        _myTable.Rows.Add("A", 2, 10000, 0, 20000)
        'DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        ' Disable adding new row
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        ' Create our medium between grid and collection
        DataGridView1.DataSource = _myTable
        CalculateTotalqty()
        CalculateTotalValue()
    End Sub
    Private Sub grid_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Dim quantity As Double = 0
        Dim price As Double = 0
        Dim discount As Double = 0
        Dim total As Double = 0

        If Not IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Quantity").Value) Then
            Integer.TryParse(CType(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Quantity").Value, String), CInt(quantity))
            _dr("Quantity") = quantity
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Quantity value is required.")
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Quantity").Value = _dr("Quantity").ToString()
            quantity = Double.Parse(CType(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Quantity").Value, String))
        End If
        If Not IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Price").Value) Then
            Integer.TryParse(CType(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Price").Value, String), CInt(price))
            _dr("Price") = price
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Price value is required.")
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Price").Value = _dr("Price").ToString()
            price = Double.Parse(CType(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Price").Value, String))
        End If
        If Not IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Discount").Value) Then
            Integer.TryParse(CType(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Discount").Value, String), CInt(discount))
            _dr("Discount") = discount
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Discount value is required.")
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Discount").Value = _dr("Discount").ToString()
            discount = Double.Parse(CType(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Discount").Value, String))
        End If
        total = (quantity * price) - (discount)
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Total").Value = total
        CalculateTotalqty()
        CalculateTotalValue()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataError
        If e.Context = DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit Then
            'MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Column {0} value is required.", e.ColumnIndex))
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellBeginEdit
        _dr = _myTable.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    End Sub
End Class



You need to specify what line the exception is thrown on. We shouldn't have to work it out from that GIF.

@jmcilhinney , Thanks for your reply , price = Double.Parse(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Price").Value) This line Code is error

That means that that cell contains NULL (ADO.NET represents database NULLs using DBNull.Value) and Double.Parse is expecting a String. If your data is nullable then you have to test for null first and only convert if there's data to convert.

BTW, for that code to compile, you would have to have Option Strict Off. You really ought to set Option Strict On in this project and set it On in the VS options, so it is On by default for all future projects. That will flag all the places that you're using implicit narrowing conversions and late binding as errors. Fixing those will force you to put more thought into what data types you're using and should be using and help avoid some run-time exceptions.

@jmcilhinney , I've updated the above code with  Option Strict On But still an error. I want when the user makes the DatagridView column empty then a MessageBox appears when the value becomes previous. Please Guide me.
